# Single quotes problem in Linux

Tags: linux

I tried to remove a folder in linux, davidanderson'spetshop_617 as a folder name. It contained a single quotes. By using the following command

```
     rm -r path/davidanderson'spetshop_617
```

I am getting this error

Error:
unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
unexpected end of file

How can i remove the folder?

Comment: Let this be a lesson to you.

Answer (score 6):

you should issue

```
rm -r path/davidanderson\'spetshop_617
```

Answer (score 5):

Wrap double quotes around the path:

```
rm -r "path/davidanderson'spetshop_617"
```

or escape the single quote in the path:

```
rm -r path/davidanderson\'spetshop_617
```